# SOAP WSDL error

Tags: php, wsdl

I'm trying to call a webservice in php. With php 5.3.0 it works fine but it must work with 5.2.0

Now i'm getting this error when I execute my webservice:
[WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from https://xx.xx.xx.xx:port/webdialer/services/WebdialerSoapService?wsdl'

I've searched the net allready, and I found that it could be a bug. I did what they suggested but it stille won't work.

This is my code:

```
 function MakeCall($linenumber, $destinationNumber, $deviceName){
 /*try {
    if(!@file_get_contents($wsdl)) {
        throw new SoapFault('Server', 'No WSDL found at ' . $wsdl);
    }*/
 try{
     $soap = new SoapClient("https://xx.xx.xx.xx:port/webdialer/services/WebdialerSoapService?wsdl",array(
  "uri" => "urn:WebdialerSoap",
  "trace" => 1,
  "exceptions" => 1)); 

  $rs2 = $soap->makeCallSoap(
   array(
    "userID"=>'xx',
    "password"=>'xx'
   ),
   $destinationNumber, // Destination number to be called
   array(
    'user'=>'user',
    'deviceName'=>$deviceName,
    'lineNumber'=>$linenumber,
    'supportEM'=>false,
    'locale'=>'English',
    'dontAutoClose'=>true,
    'dontShowCallConf'=>true
   )
  );
  return $rs2;
 } catch(SoapFault $e) {
     echo $e;
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have openssl enabled in php.ini for the 5.2.0 installation?

Comment: stupid me! That solved my problem. I enabled it on my local machine but not on my server. Thanks Catalin!